# Centering content under an image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following with CSS:
[image]

The content will be wider grid of same-sized blocks - this is just one block. So far I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="listing_items">
                <!-- listing item 1 -->
                <div class="listing_display">
                    <div class="listing_display_inner">
                        <img src="images/sports/archery_1.png">
                        <div class="listing_item_wrapper">
                            <div class="listing_item_description_1">
                                <div class="listing_item_square"></div>
                                <a href="#" class="listing_item_title">Kelly's Archery Range</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="listing_item_description_2">
                                <a href="#" class="listing_item_city">Zurich</a>
                                <a href="#" class="listing_item_country">Switzerland</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.listing_items {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.listing_display {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 380px;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    min-width: 380px;
}

.listing_display_inner {
    text-align: center;
}

.listing_display_inner>img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 380px;
}

.listing_item_wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.listing_item_description_1 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.listing_item_description_2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

And I am far from getting it right...

I am struggling to make the content under the picture do the following:
1) Always stay in the arrangement as it is on the picture. Name on left and city (location) on right.
2) If the name becomes too long it just goes to the next line

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: put your complete css. so far it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/j911b40t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I can get without tearing it all down and starting again.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.listing_items {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.listing_display {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 380px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  min-width: 380px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.listing_display_inner {} .listing_display_inner img {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 380px;
}
.listing_item_wrapper {
  /* quick clearfix */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.listing_item_description_1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  background: ;
}
.listing_item_description_2 {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="listing_items">
  <!-- listing item 1 -->
  <div class="listing_display">
    <div class="listing_display_inner">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-380-380-10.jpg">

      <div class="listing_item_wrapper">
        <div class="listing_item_description_1">
          <div class="listing_item_square"></div>
          <a href="#" class="listing_item_title">An incredbible baseball display</a>
        </div>
        <div class="listing_item_description_2">
          <a href="#" class="listing_item_city">Zurich</a>
          <a href="#" class="listing_item_country">Switzerland</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pJZoKg)

Answer (score 1):

in `.listing_item_wrapper` You use `20%` for `width`... remove it.

For both `...description` set `display:block;`, for `.listing_item_description_1` set `float:left;`, and for `.listing_item_description_2` set `float:right`;

**There is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hxpv9fn/1)**

This is only small changes of Your code to achieve what You need... nothing new.

... is that what You want?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can use Position statuses.

Example

```
 #Main_div
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            right:10px;                         
        }
 #text_div1
        {
            position:relative;
            bottom:10px;
            right:10px;                         
        }
 #text_div2
        {
            position:relative;
            bottom:10px;
            left:10px;                          
        }
```

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please change width here..

```
.listing_item_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Also try modifying these styles.

`.listing_item_wrapper` - `text-align: left;`

`.listing_item_description_2` - `text-align: right;`

`.listing_item_description_1` - `width: 230px;`

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent's position `relative` and the child you want to move to `absolute` and use the `bottom` and `left` properties, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kn5sH/107/)